# Ranking a table in vue.js and coloring after performance

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a problem with ranking my data performance i vue js. I have made the following script so far:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2> Campaign performance </h2>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Client</th>
                    <th scope="col">Campaign</th>
                    <th scope="col">Impressions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(campaign, name) in campaignPerformance.slice(0,10)" :key="campaign.campaignID">
                 <td>{{campaign.client}}</td>
                 <td>{{campaign.campaign}}</td>
                 <td>{{campaign.impressions}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
   data() {
    return {
    };
   },
  props:['campaignPerformance],
  created() {
  },
};
</script>
```

Now this give me a table with campaign performance, looking like this:
[image]
However, I would like to rank the table depending on performance, and color it looking like this:
[image]
Can anyone help here?

Comment: if you found my answer helpful dont forget to vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets handle the numbers formatting. To format your numbers with M(Million), create a method which will take input the numbers and return the value with million format.

```
formatNumber(labelValue) {
  // Nine Zeroes for Billions
  return Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+9

  ? Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+9 + "B for Billion"
  // Six Zeroes for Millions 
  : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+6

  ? Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+6 + "M for Million"
  // Three Zeroes for Thousands
  : Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) >= 1.0e+3

  ? Math.abs(Number(labelValue)) / 1.0e+3 + "K for thousands"

  : Math.abs(Number(labelValue));

}
```

The above code is quite self explanatory. We take input and match the conditions for billion million and thousands etc.

Next, we will move towards coloring our table. For that, create another method and insert bind the method to `v-style`. This method will return the color in rgba format color the rows respectively. You can set the color as per your choosing.

```
colorRows(value) {
  value--;
  var r,g,b;

  if (value < 4) {
    // green to yellow
    r = Math.floor(255 * (value / 4));
    g = 255;

  } else {
    // yellow to red
    r = 255;
    g = Math.floor(255 * ((4-value%4) / 4));
  }
  b = 0;
  let color = "rgba("+ r + "," + g + "," + b +")"; //Concat rbga for the styled to be binded
  console.log(color);
  return color; 
}
```

Finally, bind the `rowColor` and `formatNumber` method to the html and just loop the array.

```
  <tr v-for="(campaign, index) in campaignPerformance" :key="campaign.campaignID">
    <td v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': colorRows(index) }">{{campaign.client}}</td>
    <td v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': colorRows(index) }">{{campaign.campaign}}</td>
    <td v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': colorRows(index) }">
      {{formatNumber(campaign.impressions)}}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

**Complete working example:**

https://codepen.io/AhmedKhan1/pen/wvGxQOz?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly well for coloring and formattting numbers - Can you also show me how to rank the table depending on impressions. So the campaign with the highest impressions are at the top of the table?

Comment: So what you mean is to sort the array based on the impresssion?

Comment: Just sort the array when you fetch the data from API etc.

Comment: So at the table, the campaign with the most impressions is at the top and the campaign with the fewest is at the bottom of the table

Comment: Yes just sort it with respect to impressions when received from API

Comment: Great! dont forget to leave a like if you found it helpful.